# winapi - rich edit control - how to paste a text using a context menu

Tags: winapi

I create an edit window this way:

```
hwndEdit = CreateWindowEx(
   0, 
   MSFTEDIT_CLASS, 
   TEXT("EDIT"),
   WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | ES_LEFT,
   20, 
   20, 
   100,
   30,
   gHwnd, 
   NULL, 
   hInst, 
   NULL);
```

I can paste a text using a keyboard shortcut (ctrl + v) but when I use a right mouse button a context menu is not displayed (for a standard edit control it works). I couldn't find any c/c++ example code. How to enable/implement a context menu for a rich edit control ?

Comment: It's provided automatically. I expect your message loop is doing something wrong.

Comment: I use standard windows desktop application code generate by visual studio 2017. I have only added a code which creates an edit control inside a main window - gHwnd. A context menu only works for a standard edit control (CreateWindowEx lpClassName - EDIT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have created a custom edit window.

You can handle right click on the edit window via checking for [WM_CONTEXTMENU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-contextmenu) in your WndProc.

Grab the handle to the window via the wParam parameter, compare it to your edit window to see if the user right clicked the edit window.

From there, create the `popupmenu` via [CreatePopupMenu()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createpopupmenu).

Insert/Append into the menu via [InsertMenu()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-insertmenua)/[AppendMenu()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-appendmenua).

Finally, call [TrackPopupMenu()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackpopupmenu).

Code:

```
#define IDC_PASTE 102

case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
        if ((HWND)wParam == hwndEdit) 
        {
            m_hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            InsertMenu(m_hMenu, 0, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_STRING | MF_ENABLED, IDC_PASTE, L"Paste");
            TrackPopupMenu(m_hMenu, TPM_TOPALIGN | TPM_LEFTALIGN, GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam), 0, hWnd, NULL);
    }
```

Next you need to handle the paste message. As can be seen from the problem, your paste shortcut is still useful, so you can use `SendInput` to simulate paste.

Code:

```
 case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDC_PASTE:
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(hwndEdit);
                INPUT ip;
                ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                ip.ki.wScan = 0;
                ip.ki.time = 0;
                ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
                // Press the "Ctrl" key
                ip.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
                ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

                // Press the "V" key
                ip.ki.wVk = 'V';
                ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

                // Release the "V" key
                ip.ki.wVk = 'V';
                ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

                // Release the "Ctrl" key
                ip.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
                ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
            }
            break;
            ...
```

Comment: I can also paste a text using the following code: SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_PASTE, 0, 0); Is it also correct ?

Comment: @Irbis From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-rich-edit-clipboard-operations#instructions), it works.

Comment: Maybe CreatePopupMenu and InsertMenu should be moved outside events procedure ?

Comment: @Irbis This is just the code shown for reference only. You can modify it according to your needs